# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, rails-activerecord

I am trying to submit a form and getting this error: `Couldn't find Event without an ID`

Here is the controller:

```
def create
@event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
@event_sponsorship = EventSponsorship.new(params[:event_sponsorship])
@event_sponsorship.sponsor_id = current_user.id
@event_sponsorship.event_id = @event

respond_to do |format|
  if @event_sponsorship.save
    format.html { redirect_to @event_sponsorship, notice: 'Event sponsorship was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @event_sponsorship, status: :created, location: @event_sponsorship }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @event_sponsorship.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

Here is the form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@event_sponsorship) do |f| %>
<%= f.error_notification %>

<div class="signin">
<%= f.hidden_field :event_id, value: @event %>

 <%= f.hidden_field :sponsor_id, value: current_user.id %>

<%= f.button :submit, :class => "btn btn-success btn-block", value: "Yes" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

In the `create` method the `event_id` should be found from the URL. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post your error as seen in your server console, you'll see that your param 'event_id' is a sub key of (I guess) 'event_sponsorship'

Try this:

```
@event = Event.find(params[:event_sponsorship][:event_id])
```

And it's even possible that you'll need to use this code:

```
@event = Event.find(params[:event_sponsorship].delete(:event_id))
```

That would remove the 'event_id' fron your params, and allow `EventSponsorship.new` to work without error

Comment: Hi, I've tried both and neither has worked. Checked the console and it seems there is a problem the retrieving of the event_id, once the form is submitting the user_id is found but, for some reason the event_id can't be found

Comment: Started POST "/event_sponsorships" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-20 23:33:32 +0000
Processing by EventSponsorshipsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"CCjUMJW5oVit0BTvBhto1D963dCbFP3RVkBnxi/lOsI=", "event_sponsorship"=>{"event_id"=>"6", "sponsor_id"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"Yes"}
Completed 404 Not Found in 1ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Event without an ID):
  app/controllers/event_sponsorships_controller.rb:44:in `create'

Comment: I'm surprised this don't work. Try this perhaps: `@event = Event.find(params['event_sponsorship']['event_id'])`

Comment: So I guess you have an old version of rails. Glad we finally found it

Comment: I'm running 3.2.11 which version do you use?

Comment: 3.2.12, as per the changelog there were some fix in the params sanitizer https://github.com/rails/rails/compare/v3.1.11...v3.1.12